# Find observations in 10% tail after fitting to normal distribution

Tags: r

Given a sample, then fitting that to a normal distribution, how would I find the observations that fall in the 10% tail?

Say I have these 10 observations:

```
x = c(68.9322859175383, 87.9226602406337, 118.63064982191, 63.9906406656306, 
181.510804700138, 188.910377786055, 96.9295278315884, 86.2770354338514, 
95.1169692997219, 82.1328861776944)
```

I fitted them to a normal distribution:

```
MASS::fitdistr(x, 'normal')
```

which returns the `mean` and `sd` but I'm not sure how to use this information to find the points in the 10% tail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If

```
y <- MASS::fitdistr(x, 'normal')
```

then the lower 10% tail is given by

```
tail <- qnorm(0.1, y$estimate[1], y$estimate[2])

tail
[1] 53.65485
```

and you can then select `x[x<tail]` - although in this case there are none

Answer (score 1):

You need the [Quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function) of the normal distibution. It's called `qnorm`. Use the parameters `mu` and `sd` as parameters.

```
x = c(68.9322859175383, 87.9226602406337, 118.63064982191, 63.9906406656306, 
       181.510804700138, 188.910377786055, 96.9295278315884, 86.2770354338514, 
       95.1169692997219, 82.1328861776944)
p <- MASS::fitdistr(x, 'normal')
```

This is the 10% Quantile:

```
q10 <- qnorm(0.1, mean = p$estimate["mean"], sd = p$estimate["sd"])
```

Which values are at most in the 10% quantile?

```
x <= q10
```

This is the 90% Quantile:

```
q90 <- qnorm(0.9, mean = p$estimate["mean"], sd = p$estimate["sd"])
```

Which values are larger than the 90% quantile?

```
x >= q90
```

Comment: thanks,  never copy and paste in R, I tell all people... :-P

Answer (score 1):

Use `pnorm` to get the cumulative probabilities under the estimated estimated distribution.

```
pnorm(x,mean(x),sd(x))
 [1] 0.1927437 0.3316693 0.6041455 0.1634492 0.9550798 0.9688933 0.4089801
 [8] 0.3181819 0.3930217 0.2852975
```

It is not clear if you are interested in a left or a right tail, none fit a 10% lower tail (i.e. p<=0.1), but 2 fit in the upper one (p>=0.9).